# Formatar string para printar raiz quadrada, expoente

Tags: javascript, matemática

Olá, Pessoal! gostaria de saber como printar na tela, uma string formatada que mostra os símbolos de ráiz quadrada, expoente e outros símbolos matemáticos?

Iria fazer mais ou menos assim:

x^2+qrt(9)...

só que com os símbolos corretos. Sei que existe uma lib chamada MathJax, porém quando a internet não está muito boa, ocorre uma demora para a troca dos símbolos. Existe outra opção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível usar alguns plugins, um dos que eu gosto de utilizar seria o [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), seria apenas ler a documentação e ver como cada expressão precisar ser chamada para gerar uma equação.

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<p>Basta chamar a TAG 'p' e passar a expressão codificado</p>
<p>
  \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</p>
```

#### Referência: [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)